# Can't focus an Input created with JS

Tags: javascript, html, input, focus

I start saying that I'm a newbie ,my problem is that I **can't focus** the input field that i created in pure Js, I can focus it only right-clicking or using Tab.
Could anyone explain me where is the problem here and how could i fix it using simply pure JS?
As you can see i've simply added some elements in my DOM.
**HTML:**

```html
<script src="nuovaVoce.js"></script>
<div id="cla" onclick="nuovavoce()">+ nuova voce</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function nuovavoce() {

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var caselle = document.createElement("form");
  var input1 = document.createElement("input");
  var input2 = document.createElement("input");



  document.getElementById("cla").appendChild(div);
  div.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  div.style.position = "absolute";
  div.style.left = "0px";
  div.style.width = "100%";
  div.style.height = "100%";
  div.style.top = "0px";

  div.appendChild(caselle);
  caselle.setAttribute("method", "post");
  caselle.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
  caselle.setAttribute("onsubmit", "");

  caselle.appendChild(input1);
  input1.style.position = "static";
  input1.style.width = "80%";
  input1.style.height = "";
  input1.style.marginLeft = "";
  input1.style.marginTop = "";
  input1.setAttribute("name", "titolo");
  input1.setAttribute("type", "text");



  caselle.appendChild(input2);
  input2.style.position = "static";
  input2.style.width = "80%";
  input2.style.height = "";
  input2.style.marginLeft = "";
  input2.style.marginTop = "";
  input2.setAttribute("type", "submit");
  input2.setAttribute("name", "submit_categoria");
}
```

Comment: add input1.focus(); at the end of nuovavoce function

Comment: Dude it was so simple to resolve but i couldn't find it anywhere on the internet. Thank you SO much, u helped me a lot! If u write your answer in the other way i'll give u the green mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use [.focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) method.  At the end of your function you need to add:

```
add input1.focus();
```

```js
function nuovavoce() {

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var caselle = document.createElement("form");
    var input1 = document.createElement("input");
    var input2 = document.createElement("input");



    document.getElementById("cla").appendChild(div);
    div.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    div.style.left = "0px";
    div.style.width = "100%";
    div.style.height = "100%";
    div.style.top = "0px";

    div.appendChild(caselle);
    caselle.setAttribute("method", "post");
    caselle.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
    caselle.setAttribute("onsubmit", "");

    caselle.appendChild(input1);
    input1.style.position = "static";
    input1.style.width = "80%";
    input1.style.height = "";
    input1.style.marginLeft = "";
    input1.style.marginTop = "";
    input1.setAttribute("name", "titolo");
    input1.setAttribute("type", "text");



    caselle.appendChild(input2);
    input2.style.position = "static";
    input2.style.width = "80%";
    input2.style.height = "";
    input2.style.marginLeft = "";
    input2.style.marginTop = "";
    input2.setAttribute("type", "submit");
    input2.setAttribute("name", "submit_categoria");
    input1.focus();
}
```

```html
<div id="cla" onclick="nuovavoce()">+ nuova voce</div>
```